# warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity drupal

Tags: simplexml, php

I am getting the following errors.

> warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

in this code

```
$a = base_path()."sites/default/files/q.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($a);
```

I do this in drupal 6.

Comment: Your path to file is incorrect. What is the answer you wanted?

Comment: Did you check with `file_exists`? What is your working directory (`system('pwd');`)? Is the current directory part of your include path?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the error message is pretty descriptive. It cannot find the file, or the permissions are wrong. Double check the permissions on your server. You may also want to try a quick debug statement like:

```
var_dump(base_path()."sites/default/files/q.xml"); 
die();
```

To print out the path real quick to verify it is what you want.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue and I checked File is Present and I have given permissions to 777! still its giving same error.

Comment: @GaneshPatil: External entity also can mean an external entity in the XML file could not be loaded. You probably want to disable external entity loading or hook into the: [`libxml_set_external_entity_loader()`](http://php.net/libxml_set_external_entity_loader).